# Revised: Conditional probability sports league involving sums of numbers

Tags: probability, gambling

Suppose we have a sports league where 45 games will be played and the results listed. A gambler chooses 8 games from the 45 that will be played. Her hope is to choose games that will end in a tie. For each tied game, the gambler gets 3 points; if the visiting team wins, the gambler gets 2 points; and if the home team wins, the gambler gets 1.5 points. In each game, the home team's probability of winning is 0.5; the probability of the visiting team's winning is 0.4; and the
probability of a tie is 0.1. So, what is our gambler's probability of getting a total of 22 points
or more?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that $22$ is a pretty high total, considering that if each of the $8$ games ties (a virtually impossible outcome) the gambler only gets $24$ points.  Thus, enumerating the good scenarios should be pretty easy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know where to start, especially with the probabilities piled on top. Not even sure how to categorize the problem.

Comment: I told you where to start:  enumerate the winning scenarios for the gambler.  There really aren't very many.  $8$ ties is a winning scenario.  What other ones can you find?

Comment: Please see the **Edit - Tools** section of [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.